# Optimization due to constructor initializer list

Tags: c++, performance, constructor, initializer-list

> Constructors should initialize all its member objects through
>   initializer list if possible. It is more efficient than building the
>   constructors via assignment inside the constructor body.

Could someone explain, why it is more efficient to use the initializer list with the help of an example?

Comment: For the sake of completeness- if we assume that the optimiser is sane, does this issue reduce to nothing more than "default constructor then operator= versus a specific constructor"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider this program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  A() { std::cout << "A::A()\n"; }
  A(int) { std::cout << "A::(int)\n"; }
  void operator=(const A&) { std::cout << "A::operator=(const A&)\n"; }
};

struct C1 {
  A a;
  C1(int i) { 
    a = i;
  }
};

struct C2 {
  A a;
  C2(int i)  : a(i) {}
};

int main() {
  std::cout << "How expesive is it to create a C1?\n";
  { C1 c1(7); }
  std::cout << "How expensive is it to create a C2?\n";
  { C2 c2(7); }
}
```

On my system (Ubuntu 11.10, g++ 4.6.1), the program produces this output:

```
How expesive is it to create a C1?
A::A()
A::(int)
A::operator=(const A&)
How expensive is it to create a C2?
A::(int)
```

Now, consider why it is doing that. In the first case, `C1::C1(int)`, `a` must be default-constructed before `C1`'s constructor can be invoked. Then it is must assigned to via `operator=`. In my trivial example, there is no `int` assignment operator available, so we have to construct an `A` out of an int. Thus, the cost of not using an initializer is: one default constructor, one `int` constructor, and one assignment operator.

In the second case, `C2::C2(int)`, only the `int` constructor is invoked. Whatever the cost of a default `A` constructor might be, clearly the cost of `C2:C2(int)` is not greater than the cost of `C1::C1(int)`.

---

Or, consider this alternative. Suppose that we add the following member to `A`:

```
void operator=(int) { std::cout << "A::operator=(int)\n"; }
```

Then the output would read:

```
How expesive is it to create a C1?
A::A()
A::operator=(int)
How expensive is it to create a C2?
A::(int)
```

Now is is impossible to say generally which form is more efficient. In your specific class, is the cost of a default constructor plus the cost of an assignment more expensive than a non-default constructor? If so, then the initialization list is more efficient. Otherwise it isn't.

Most classes that I've ever written would be more efficiently initialized in an init list. But, that is a rule-of-thumb, and may not be true for every possible case.

Comment: Waw..a great way to explain with an example. I understood my doubt and you threw more light for C++ beginner than the question expects :)..

Comment: I have a doubt. Why should the `int` constructor be called in the case of `C1 c1(7)`. Just the default constructor invocation and assignment operator should have been invoked right?

Comment: @LinuxPenseur - the default constructor is called to create the temproary which is the right-hand-side of the assignment expression. That temporary must be created in order to invoke `A::operator=(const A&)`. If `A` had been more complete -- if it included `A::operator=(int)` -- then the default constructor would not have been invoked.

Comment: @LinuxPenseur: the assignment operator takes an `A` as a parameter; consequently, the statement `a = 7` first creates a temporary `A` (using `A::A(int)`) before invoking the assignment operator. The literal `7` is converted to an `A`.

Comment: @Rob: This is not the default constructor that is called, but the constructor parameterized by an int.

Comment: @LucTouraille - Thank you for your correction, you are right, I misspoke. My comment should have read "the `int` constructor is called to create ... then the `int` constructor would not have ...".

Comment: It's a bit strange that your `struct A` has no data at all, just functions.

Answer (score 9):

Well, otherwise you call the default constructor and *then* perform an assignment. That's one step longer and may get really inefficient depending on the nature of initialization.

Comment: Does the initializer list save CPU cycles?. Could u explain related to that?

Comment: Depending on the nature of default construct and assignment for y our particular objects it may save tons of cpu cycles. Again, because assignment in the constructor body means *first* executing default constructor, *then* discarding (likely) whatever (or part of what) it's done by assigning the new value. Which is obviously more work for cpu than putting the right data in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Because it initialises directly, instead of default initialising and then assigning. It likely won't matter performance-wise for PODs, but it will if the type constructor is doing heavy-weight work.

Also, in some cases you *must* use init list, so you should always do it for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

From the [C++FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) :

> Consider the following constructor that initializes member object x_ using an initialization list: Fred::Fred() : x_(whatever) { }. The most common benefit of doing this is improved performance. For example, if the expression whatever is the same type as member variable x_, the result of the whatever expression is constructed directly inside x_ — the compiler does not make a separate copy of the object. Even if the types are not the same, the compiler is usually able to do a better job with initialization lists than with assignments.
>
> The other (inefficient) way to build constructors is via assignment, such as: Fred::Fred() { x_ = whatever; }. In this case the expression whatever causes a separate, temporary object to be created, and this temporary object is passed into the x_ object's assignment operator. Then that temporary object is destructed at the ;. That's inefficient.
>
> As if that wasn't bad enough, there's another source of inefficiency when using assignment in a constructor: the member object will get fully constructed by its default constructor, and this might, for example, allocate some default amount of memory or open some default file. All this work could be for naught if the whatever expression and/or assignment operator causes the object to close that file and/or release that memory (e.g., if the default constructor didn't allocate a large enough pool of memory or if it opened the wrong file).

Answer (score 0):

To prevent double initialization.

```
class B
{
//whatever
};

class A
{
   B _b;
public:
   A(B& b)
};
```

Now the two cases:

```
//only initializes _b once via a copy constructor
A::A(B& b) : _b(b)
{
}

//initializes _b once before the constructor body, and then copies the new value
A::A(B& b)
{
   //_b is already initialized here
   //....
   //one extra instruction:
   _b = b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as POD types are concerned, the initialization and the assignment should be equivalent, since they are left uninitialized if no initialization is performed explicitly, so the only operation remains the assignment.

Things are different for classes which have default constructors and assignment operators: instead of creating the object directly in the correct state, first the default constructor has to be called, and then the assignment operator (inside the body of the constructor). This is surely more inefficient than initializing the object with the correct constructor straight from the beginning (two steps instead of one, and the first step - default construction - is usually completely wasted).

The direct initialization also yields the advantage that you can be sure that, if the execution reached the body of the constructor, all the various fields are already in their "correct" state.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a data member in your class which is std::string type. When the constructor of this class is executed, the default constructor string class would be called automatically because objects are initialized before the body of the constructor.

If you are assigning the string inside the body of the constructor, then a temporary object would be created and given to the string's assignment operator. The temporary object will be destroyed at the end of the assignment statement. If you do this in the initializer list, a temporary object will not be created.

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(string s);
    ~Person();
private:
    string name;
};


// case 1
Person::Person(string s)
{
   name = s;   // creates a temporary object
}

// case 2
Person::Person(string s):name(s) {} // whereas this will not create a temporary object.
```

Answer (score 0):

because if you are using the inizializer list what you are calling is the constructor copy of that object .

While if you initialize objects inside the constructor body you are doing an assignment.

example:
here i m calling  the copy constructor of int.

```
  myClass::myClass( int x ) : member(x) {}
```

while here i m calling the operator=(const int& ). the asignment

```
    myClass::myClass( int x )
    {
         member = x;
    }
```

usually the asignment does more operation then a simple copy.
you must keep in account also temporary object!