# Delegate method to remove self: possible problems?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to `delete this`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550189/is-it-safe-to-delete-this)

Okay, I want to use some `Object` and its delegate `ObjectDelegate`.
Here is the sample code:

```c++
class ObjectDelegate;

class Object {
private:
    int a;
    ObjectDelegate *delegate;
    void crazyMethod();

public:
    Object();
    ~Object();

    void setDelegate(ObjectDelegate*);
};

Object::Object() {
    delegate = NULL;
    a = 9001;
    std::cout << "Object Constructor";
}

Object::~Object() {
    std::cout << "Object Destructor";
}

void Object::crazyMethod() {
    if(delegate != NULL) {
        delegate->deleteMe(this);
    }
}

//-----

class ObjectDelegate {
public:
    virtual void deleteMe(Object*) = 0;
};

//------

class DelegateItself : public ObjectDelegate {
    void deleteMe(Object*);
};

void DelegateItself::deleteMe(Object *object) {
    delete object;
}
```

I often use this approach in Objective-C and Java, but how will it work in the C++-from-the-box?
My question is: at the time I running one method in the `Object` I call from it another method in the another object (`DelegateItself`) and delete the `Object`. The stack will be:

- Object::~Object()
- DelegateItself::deleteMe()
- Object::crazyMethod()

So after the destructor method ends `deleteMe` method also end (after some time). But what will be happen with `crazyMethod` of non-existing object? If I try to use variable `Object::a` I will have possibility to get a garbage instead of real value (data will be invalidated) [hope I understood C++ logic]. If I try to call another method in `Object` I will possibly crash [hope so too]. But will be it **guaranteed** to end the `crazyMethod` correctly if there are no subsequent methods will be called?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but I noticed you are doing assignments in constructor body, if you are new to c++ you should read about using intializer lists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386848/optimization-due-to-constructor-initializer-list

Comment: Please, don't do that. -- The whole humanity